# Twitter card image appears in validator but not appearing in any of three tweets below Any Ideas. Thanks. Robert

Tags: twitter, card

My test site is http://birdbreath.com/index3.html

Here are the meta details. The validator renders correctly.

```
<!- Twitter Card data -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@DailyBirdBereath">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="Robert Seymour">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Today's new Birdbreath cartoon">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Funny BirdBreath cartoons.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://birdbreath.com/images1/tw.png?4362984378">
```

However the tweet renders the card without the chosen image.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
 
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-text="Check out today&#39;s BirdBreath cartoon" data-url="http://BirdBreath.com" data-via="DailyBirdBreath" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
 
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://birdbreath.com&text=your%20text">Tweet</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I referenced the domain only (http://birdbreath.com) and it renders perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).